# How to standardize categorical data that is skewed to 1 value for predictions using keras or sklean

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am currently using Keras to provide a sequential model for my data, but am thinking my data is skewed to much because of one of my categories contains 7 values and one of those accounts for 85% of the data. I am thinking I need to standardize the columns by adjusting the weights. Will the prepossessing function from sklean be able to help with this?
Below is the current code I have so far:

```
# load the dataset as a pandas DataFrame
data = read_csv(filename)
data = pd.DataFrame(data,columns= ['A','B','C'])
datas = data
# retrieve numpy array
dataset = data.values
# split into input (X) and output (y) variables
X = dataset[:, :-1]
y = dataset[:,-1]
# format all fields as string
X = X.astype(str)
# reshape target to be a 2d array
y = y.reshape((len(y), 1))
# load the dataset
def load_dataset(filename):
    # load the dataset as a pandas DataFrame
    data = read_csv(filename, header=None)
    # retrieve numpy array
    dataset = data.values
    # split into input (X) and output (y) variables
    X = dataset[:, :-1]
    y = dataset[:,-1]
    # format all fields as string
    X = X.astype(str)
    # reshape target to be a 2d array
    y = y.reshape((len(y), 1))
    return X, y
# split into train and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)
stdscaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X_train)
X_scaled  = stdscaler.transform(x)
X_train_scaled = stdscaler.transform(X_train)
X_test_scaled  = stdscaler.transform(X_test)
print('Train', X_train.shape, y_train.shape)
print('Test', X_test.shape, y_test.shape)
# prepare input data
def prepare_inputs(X_train, X_test):
    ohe = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
    ohe.fit(X_train)
    X_train_enc = ohe.transform(X_train)
    X_test_enc = ohe.transform(X_test)
    return X_train_enc, X_test_enc
# prepare target
def prepare_targets(y_train, y_test):
    le = LabelEncoder()
    le.fit(y_train)
    y_train_enc = le.transform(y_train)
    y_test_enc = le.transform(y_test)
    return y_train_enc, y_test_enc
# prepare input data
X_train_enc, X_test_enc = prepare_inputs(X_train_scaled, X_test_scaled)
# prepare output data
y_train_enc, y_test_enc = prepare_targets(y_train, y_test)
# define the model
model =Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=X_train_enc.shape[1], activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
# compile the keras model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# fit the keras model on the dataset
model.fit(X_train_enc, y_train_enc, epochs=100, batch_size=16, verbose=2)
# evaluate the keras model
_, accuracy = model.evaluate(X_test_enc, y_test_enc, verbose=0)
print('Accuracy: %.2f' % (accuracy*100))
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest to go through the example in keras documentation. You are facing class imbalanced problem .Check out this [url](https://keras.io/examples/structured_data/imbalanced_classification/).

You need to use `class_weight`  argument while fitting your model